Lineage OS Android.bp file errors: Soong default config property "board_wlan_device" must be one of [accepted values]
I was building Lineage OS 21.0 for a SM-J320FN, I I get to the finial "brunch" part and it returns this error whewre it analyzing Android.bp files and generating a ninja file
[100% 1/1] analyzing Android.bp files and generating ninja file at out/soong/build.lineage_j3xnlte.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.lineage_j3xnlte.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_out "out/soong"     --out "out"     --soong_variables out/soong/soong.lineage_j3xnlte.variables -o out/soong/build.lineage_j3xnlte.ninja --globListDir lineage_j3xnlte --globFile out/soong/globs-lineage_j3xnlte.ninja -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used.lineage_j3xnlte.build Android.bp
error: hardware/synaptics/wlan/synadhd/wifi_hal/Android.bp:29:1: module "libwifi-hal-syna-defaults": Soong config property "board_wlan_device" must be one of [bcmdhd synadhd qcwcn mrvl nxp MediaTek realtek emulator rtl slsi wlan0], found "sc2341"
error: hardware/broadcom/wlan/bcmdhd/wifi_hal/Android.bp:29:1: module "libwifi-hal-bcm-defaults": Soong config property "board_wlan_device" must be one of [bcmdhd synadhd qcwcn mrvl nxp MediaTek realtek emulator rtl slsi wlan0], found "sc2341"
error: frameworks/opt/net/wifi/libwifi_hal/Android.bp:68:1: module "libwifi_hal_cflags_defaults": Soong config property "board_wlan_device" must be one of [bcmdhd synadhd qcwcn mrvl nxp MediaTek realtek emulator rtl slsi wlan0], found "sc2341"
error: frameworks/opt/net/wifi/libwifi_hal/Android.bp:143:1: module "google_wifi_config_lib_defaults": Soong config property "board_wlan_device" must be one of [bcmdhd synadhd qcwcn mrvl nxp MediaTek realtek emulator rtl slsi wlan0], found "sc2341"
error: frameworks/opt/net/wifi/libwifi_hal/Android.bp:152:1: module "libwifi_hal_vendor_impl_defaults": Soong config property "board_wlan_device" must be one of [bcmdhd synadhd qcwcn mrvl nxp MediaTek realtek emulator rtl slsi wlan0], found "sc2341"
error: frameworks/opt/net/wifi/libwifi_hal/Android.bp:192:1: module "libwifi_hal_vendor_deps_defaults": Soong config property "board_wlan_device" must be one of [bcmdhd synadhd qcwcn mrvl nxp MediaTek realtek emulator rtl slsi wlan0], found "sc2341"
error: external/wpa_supplicant_8/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant/Android.bp:31:1: module "lib_vendor_wpa_supplicant": Soong config property "board_wlan_device" must be one of [bcmdhd synadhd qcwcn mrvl nxp MediaTek realtek emulator rtl slsi wlan0], found "sc2341"

It seems that the "board_wlan_device" property in the Android.bp files is not matching the expected values. The error specifies that it should be one of the accepted values, but it was found to be "sc2341".
I never change that value to sc2341 myself it was originated from a default value of modules of board_wlan_device like libwifi-hal-syna-defaults, however these module could not be found or edited, in fact, the value "sc2341" never existed in my code at all
